# Create a Lambda Expression having a WHERE IN Clause

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, expression-trees

I want to create a lambda expression dynamically for this:

```
List<Coverage>? excludedCoverage = originalCoverage.Where(a => currentCoverage.Select(k => k.CoverageId).Contains(a.CoverageId) == false).ToList();
```

I have this two lists:

```
var originalCoverage = new List<Coverage>() { 
new Coverage { CoverageId = 1, Name = "Name 1", }, 
new Coverage { CoverageId = 2, Name = "Name 2", }, 
new Coverage { CoverageId = 3, Name = "Name 3", }, 
new Coverage { CoverageId = 4, Name = "Name 4", }, 
new Coverage { CoverageId = 5, Name = "Name 5", }, 
};

var currentCoverage = new List<Coverage>() { 
new Coverage { CoverageId = 4, Name = "Name 4", }, 
new Coverage { CoverageId = 5, Name = "Name 5", }, 
};
```

I have the following codes which work for a basic WHERE clause:

```
var parameterExpression = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Coverage), "a");
var property = Expression.Property(parameterExpression, "CoverageId");
var expression = Expression.Equal(property, Expression.Constant(0));
var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<Coverage, bool>>(expression, parameterExpression);
var createLamda = lambda.Compile();

var newDatas = currentCoverage?.Where(createLamda).ToList();
```

How can I write an the WHERE IN clause using dynamic lambda expression?

```
List<Coverage>? excludedCoverage = originalCoverage.Where(a => currentCoverage.Select(k => k.CoverageId).Contains(a.CoverageId) == false).ToList();
```

Thanks

Comment: LINQPad is an excellent tool for determining how the C# compiler converts lambda code into `Expression` trees. Define a variable that is the expression you want to create, and use the `Dump` method to view how it is built.

Comment: In your example your Where uses closure on `currentCoverage` variable and typically .NET creates anonymous type for these cases so it won't work with expr trees. But you can try to make an expression that gets `currentCoverage` parameter and returns back a Func so it's `originalCoverage.Where(someLamba(currentCoverage))`

Comment: @SergeyLitvinov can you please provide a sample code on how to achieve this. Thanks

Comment: While it is easy, I do not see reason to do that. What you are trying to do in general? Maybe some generic function for that?

Comment: I have been able to resolve it by writing a not contain expression and passing an array of int (```currentCoverage.Select(k => k.CoverageId```)) in the expression.